# Как задать для Ajax очередь запроса?

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Чтобы невозможно было послать очередной запрос, пока не пришел ответ от посланного?

Comment: так время ожидания или очередь ?

Comment: Очередь, тему сейчас подправлю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Такую](http://jsfiddle.net/qLJrw/)?

```
$.request = (function () {
    var queue = $.Deferred().resolve();

    return function (options) {
        function _call () {
            return $.ajax(options);
        }

        return (queue = queue.then(_call, _call));
    };
})();

$.request({ url: "/foo" }).always(function () {
    console.log(1);
});

$.request({ url: "/bar" }).always(function () {
    console.log(2);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var flag = true;
...
if(flag){
    flag = false;
    $.ajax( ... (){
        ...
        success: function(){
            ....
            flag = true;
        }
    };
}
```

как-то так...

Comment: надо ещё очередь организовать :)

Comment: эмм, я понял вопрос так, как его задали ;)